# Regex to replace all occurrences of li tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, rtf

I want to replace all occurrences of li tags in a string with "\par {\pntext\f1 ''B7\tab}" and then append whatever data was within tags to the end of it.

Basically converting html to rtf format.

e.g

```
<ul><li>list1 line1</li></ul>
<ul><li><span>list2 line1</span></li></ul>
```

In the end i want to remove all ul tags

```
function convertHtmlToRtf(html) {
   var richText = html;

    richText = richText.replace(/<(?:b|strong)(?:\s+[^>]*)?>/ig, "{\\b\n");

    return richText;
}
```

Comment: That is serious because you didn't mention what approach you want to use to do the replacement.

Comment: i am using a javascript function to do that..I have also tagged javascript and jquery in my question. I have also mentioned i am looking for a regex to do that in my question

Comment: May I ask why have you tagged jQuery? Maybe that will give a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve (might simplify the solution)  - usually regex is unrelated to jQuery, so I assume you might be using jQuery to parse something

Comment: @AlexCorreiaSantos I have added my code above i want to do something like this for the <ul><li> tags so they can be converted easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad, but since you say you are using javascript and want a Regex. Then I assume you have a string and want to replace pairs of `<li></li>` with the given string. Also assuming that your HTML is always very simple and predictable (no `<li>`s within `<li>`s), then you could do something like this:

```
var str = "<ul><li>list1</li></ul>\n<ul><li><span>list2 line1</span></li></ul>";
str.replace(/<li( [^>]*){0,1}>(.*)<\/li>/, "\\par {\\pntext\f1 ''B7\\tab} $2");
```

Here I'm using a regular expressions that matches a pair of `<li>` and replace them by that magic string but keeping whatever is inside (note you can easily extend it to also remove the `ul` if necessary. Ending result:

```
<ul>\par {\pntext1 ''B7\tab} list1</ul>
<ul>\par {\pntext1 ''B7\tab} <span>list2 line1</span></ul>
```

Now you can notice right away that it won't remove tags inside - so the `<span>` will be left there. If you can use jQuery, then it might be easier to convert the nodes correctly than using Regex (which can get quite complicated)

Edit:

Since it's been clarified that `jQuery` can be used to help on the parsing, then here is a simple example of how you could use it:

https://jsfiddle.net/nazy8sc6/2/

```
var html = "<ul><li>list1 <b>line1</b></li></ul><ul><li><span>list2 line1</span></li></ul>";

var TAB_STR = "\\par {\\pntext1 ''B7\\tab}";

function convertLi(parent, node) {
  var convertedText = TAB_STR + " " + $(node).text() + "<br>";
  var convertedNode = $('<span></span>').html(convertedText);
  $(parent).append(convertedNode);
}

function convertHtmlToRtf(html) {
  var result = $('<span></span>');
  $(html).find('li').each((_, node) => {
    convertLi(result, $(node));
  })
  return result.html().replace(/<br \>/g, "\n");
}

var res = convertHtmlToRtf(html);

console.log(res);
```

In this solution, you simply find all `<li>` tags and extract the content from it - I keep the original HTML always there and simply copy the converted content into a new HTML from which we finally extract the fully converted text. Hope this helps you, but let me know if I haven't managed to explain myself very well.

Comment: i can use jquery too

Comment: Do you know how the HTML will look like ahead of the conversion? (e.g. will it always be as simple as the one you've sent?)

Comment: i can ignore the nested li's for now but there could be other tags like <span> or <b> or <i> etc

Comment: I have edited my response to show how you can do it with jQuery. I personally prefer and it's much easier to support nested li's and many other tags since the parsing is taken care for you. You can improve the code quite a lot, but hopefully it helps you understand how you could use jQuery to help on the conversion (try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/nazy8sc6/2/)